# Unable to install channels (django) using pipenv

Tags: python, django, django-channels, pipenv

When I attempt to install [django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) using pipenv, it fails, purportedly because it cannot find "zope-interface" version 4.5.0 in https://pypi.python.org/simple.

```
$ pipenv install channels
Installing channels…
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting channels
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/ea/65e947afe102b1b5798f6890479426e8f481df0ec7a4cbba21bdd2897ef9/channels-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: Django>=1.11 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from channels) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: asgiref~=2.3 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from channels) (2.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: daphne~=2.2 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from channels) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Django>=1.11->channels) (2018.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: async-timeout<4.0,>=2.0 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from asgiref~=2.3->channels) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: autobahn>=0.18 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from daphne~=2.2->channels) (18.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: twisted>=18.7 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from daphne~=2.2->channels) (18.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: txaio>=18.8.1 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from autobahn>=0.18->daphne~=2.2->channels) (18.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.11.0 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from autobahn>=0.18->daphne~=2.2->channels) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: PyHamcrest>=1.9.0 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from twisted>=18.7->daphne~=2.2->channels) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: zope.interface>=4.4.2 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from twisted>=18.7->daphne~=2.2->channels) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from twisted>=18.7->daphne~=2.2->channels) (18.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: attrs>=17.4.0 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from twisted>=18.7->daphne~=2.2->channels) (18.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: incremental>=16.10.1 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from twisted>=18.7->daphne~=2.2->channels) (17.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: Automat>=0.3.0 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from twisted>=18.7->daphne~=2.2->channels) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: constantly>=15.1 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from twisted>=18.7->daphne~=2.2->channels) (15.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from PyHamcrest>=1.9.0->twisted>=18.7->daphne~=2.2->channels) (40.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna>=2.5 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from hyperlink>=17.1.1->twisted>=18.7->daphne~=2.2->channels) (2.7)
Installing collected packages: channels
Successfully installed channels-2.1.3

Adding channels to Pipfile's [packages]…
Pipfile.lock (bd0b0a) out of date, updating to (7cafae)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Updated Pipfile.lock (bd0b0a)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (bd0b0a)…
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 27/27 — 00:00:02
An error occurred while installing zope-interface==4.5.0 --hash=sha256:21506674d30c009271fe68a242d330c83b1b9d76d62d03d87e1e9528c61beea6 --hash=sha256:3d184aff0756c44fff7de69eb4cd5b5311b6f452d4de28cb08343b3f21993763 --hash=sha256:467d364b24cb398f76ad5e90398d71b9325eb4232be9e8a50d6a3b3c7a1c8789 --hash=sha256:57c38470d9f57e37afb460c399eb254e7193ac7fb8042bd09bdc001981a9c74c --hash=sha256:9ada83f4384bbb12dedc152bcdd46a3ac9f5f7720d43ac3ce3e8e8b91d733c10 --hash=sha256:a1daf9c5120f3cc6f2b5fef8e1d2a3fb7bbbb20ed4bfdc25bc8364bc62dcf54b --hash=sha256:e6b77ae84f2b8502d99a7855fa33334a1eb6159de45626905cb3e454c023f339 --hash=sha256:e881ef610ff48aece2f4ee2af03d2db1a146dc7c705561bd6089b2356f61641f --hash=sha256:f41037260deaacb875db250021fe883bf536bf6414a4fd25b25059b02e31b120! Will try again.
Installing initially failed dependencies…
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple00
Collecting zope-interface==4.5.0 

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement zope-interface==4.5.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-yh0ggj8v-requirements/pipenv-t7csyjxt-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.2, 4.4.3)
No matching distribution found for zope-interface==4.5.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-yh0ggj8v-requirements/pipenv-t7csyjxt-requirement.txt (line 1))

  ☤  ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/1 — 00:00:00
```

Obviously this is not the output from the first time I tried it, since most of the requirements are already satisfied. One in particular that is notable is the 11th in the list of already-satisfied-requirements:

```
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: zope.interface>=4.4.2 in /home/dan/.local/share/virtualenvs/gmtools-QMaEj5K6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from twisted>=18.7->daphne~=2.2->channels) (4.5.0)
```

So if zope.interface 4.5.0 is already installed, why can't it be found? Is it because `zope-interface` and `zope.interface` are different things? I'd be less confused if the actual meat of the error message, didn't end with `(from versions: 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.2, 4.4.3)` -- these are the versions prior to 4.5.0 of `zope.interface`, so `zope-interface` is seemingly an alias. If you go to the index that the installation says it's using, https://pypi.python.org/simple, you can find `zope.interface` but not `zope-interface` at all. `zope.interface` has a version 4.5.0. So if it's looking under a name that doesn't exist, how does it find previous versions? And if it's some kind of alias, why doesn't it find 4.5.0?

I'm assuming this is an issue with my configuration, but I don't know whether it relates to channels or pipenv. Happy to include additional information but I don't know what would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has seemingly resolved itself. I did the following steps:

1. `$ pipenv run pip install channels`
2. Manually put a line in your Pipfile, `channels="*"`
3. `$ pipenv lock`

But I don't think this is what actually solved the problem -- now if I just run...

```
$ pipenv uninstall channels
$ pipenv install channels
```

...it also works just fine, which wasn't happening before. Perhaps there was some kind of issue with an old cached version of https://pypi.python.org/simple ?

Using pipenv version 2018.10.9, pip version 18.1, and python 3.6.6.

Comment: Apparently it's a problem with pip:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5870
https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.interface/issues/124

Comment: Aha, thanks for finding that @Karlis! I have accepted this answer but if it matters to you, feel free to post this as an answer and I'll accept that instead.